# How configure apache to allow simultaneous requests from the same ip

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I am working on project in `Zend Framework 2` using `apache 2` (`develop` on `windows`, `production` on `linux`). All requests sent to server are queued (second start after first ends) locally and on production. I need to configure `apache` to allow simultaneous requests from the same ip and browser.

I am not using file based session so `session_write _close()` won't help. What's wrong with this config?

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "C:\xampp\tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 1


<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
LockFile "logs/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_beos_module>
    StartThreads            10
    MaxClients              50
    MaxRequestsPerThread 10000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild      0
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers           2
    MinSpareThreads        5
    MaxSpareThreads       10
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      150
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
    #Win32DisableAcceptEx
</IfModule>
```

ServerLimit is not set.

Comment: What is the value for `ServerLimit` ?

Comment: This question probably fits better at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: "I am not using file based session so session_write _close() won't help"...."session.save_handler = files" ? You've provided a big long list of configurations - but you didn't say *which* MPM you are using.

Comment: did you get solution for this. I am facing same problem.

Comment: It was my fault. I used file based session. After genereting csrf token my session was locked until the end of  request. I had to manually close session in some places in code.

Answer (score 0):

Are those requests from your browser or from some wget / fopen terminal command.
If they are from the browser it's not the server configuration problem, but the browser itself doesn't allow multiple requests to the same domain.